# Objective C : is bad practice using self as file's owner in init method?

Tags: objective-c, tableview, nib

I'm noob in ObjC, I'm trying to understand some basic concept that seems to be confused also in the thousands of tutorial in the web. My problem is with the management of the file's owner. For example, if I want a custom cell in a `UITableView` object, I need:

```
1) to make, in Interface Builder, a NIB file with my custom cell
2) create my `CustomCellControllerClass` and set is as Custom Class
   in the Identity Inspector;
3) in my `CustomCellControllerClass` add the IBOutlet property
4) connect every item in my NIB file with respective Outlet
```

So, I have in my connection inspector something like this

```
 item --- File's Owner
```

Now, begin problems: between all methods proposed, the most "clean" to me seems to be initializing my custom cell in `init` method in my `CustomCellControllerClass`
; something like this:

```
-(id) init
 {
   self=[super init];
   self=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]
        loadNibName:@"CustomCellNib" 
        owner: self options:nil] lastObject];
   return self;
 }
```

Now, when I start the program all seems ok, but...I can't control the Outlets! 
I think because I set as Owner an old instance of the `self` object, `loadNibName:Owner:options:` returns a new object with owner the old `self` object. So, the bind between Outlets is made with the old self object.
I would that my loaded Nib has owner itself (`loadNibName:Owner:options:` return CustomCellControllerClass objects, so could not be strange set it as owner of itself), but seems it's not possible.. All this seems to me terribly recursive!
The way I found to partially "resolve" the problems is the follow:

```
-(id) init
 {
   self=[super init];
   CustomCellControllerClass* ccp=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                  loadNibName:@"CustomCellNib" 
                                  owner: self options:nil] lastObject];
   [self addSubView:ccp];
   return self;
 }
```

so, I don't lose my original `self` reference and I can handle my property. 
The problem is that now my CustomCell is just a subview, with all the problems of the case, I would to make it the "main" view.
Is my reasoning right? Where I wrong? How could resolve these problems in a better way?

Comment: there is nothing wrong about it. However, loading cells in this cell is a really deprecated concept. Nowadays you can just register the nib with the table and it will be creating the cells for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer..but I don't understand why tutorials still use this practice of set owner=self in init method.. How can I resolve in a more general way without adding a subview?

Comment: ok..but registering the nib with the table remains the problem of set the file's owner..

Comment: No owner needed: `[self.table registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyClass" bundle:nil]`. There is no need for your cell to have any owner. Your cell shouldn't connect anything to any owner.

Comment: I have setValue:forUndefinedKey: exception ....

Comment: Just remove all the connections to the owner.

Comment: :)) and then how can I use my IB property in the cell??

Comment: Connect them to the cell view, not to the owner.

Comment: @volperossa When you register the NIB, the owner is the table view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registering the NIB with the table view is the correct way to handle this.

---

To answer your question directly, reassigning `self` to the first result of `-loadNibName:owner:options:` is a total [kludge](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kludge)! But… sometimes a kludge is what's needed.

As a side note, don't pass `self` as the owner, pass `nil`, and use a class method for the NIB name, it will make subclassing easier.

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *name = [[self class] nibName];
    self = [bundle loadNibName:name owner:nil options:nil].firstObject;
    return self;
}

+ (NSString *)nibName
{
    return @"CustomCellNib";
}
```

---

Here is an updated regarding using `self` as the owner. In the code sample, you passed `self` as the owner, then reassigned `self` to a new object.

```
-(id) init
 {
   /* old self */self=[super init];
   /* NIB object */self=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]
        loadNibName:@"CustomCellNib" 
        owner: /* old self */self options:nil] lastObject];
   return /* NIB object */self;
 }
```

As you can see, the owner is the old self, but the returned value is the NIB object. Anything assigned to the owner in the NIB will be assigned to the old self and is lost.

---

The solution is to never use the owner in the NIB when you have this kind of setup, any outlets you need to setup must be established to the NIB object.

Comment: passing `nil`, I get that my NIB has no owner, then give the classic exception  setValue:forUndefinedKey beacuse Outlets are linked with owner that is setted nil !

Comment: @volperossa any values you assign to the owner are lost. Read my update.